# Avoid calling the same function over and over again

Tags: java

I have a function that builds a connection to a docker. You don't really need to understand much but all I want is to make sure the IP and port is always the same as in my app (Settings.getSettings())

```
 public static DockerClient dockerClient() {

    try {

        Settings settings = Settings.getSettings();
        DockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
                .withDockerHost("tcp://" + settings.getDockerIP() + ":" + settings.getDockerPort())
                .withDockerConfig("/home/user/.docker/config.json")
                .build();

        DockerCmdExecFactory dockerCmdExecFactory = new JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory()
                .withMaxTotalConnections(200)
                .withMaxPerRouteConnections(200);

        DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config)
                .withDockerCmdExecFactory(dockerCmdExecFactory)
                .build();

        return dockerClient;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And everytime I want to do something I'm calling this function. Example:

```
public static void startContainer(String containerName) {
    DockerClient dockerClient = dockerClient();
 ....
  public static List<Image> getImages() {
    List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>(dockerClient().listImagesCmd().withShowAll(true).exec());
 ....
```

**Isn't there a more efficient way to handle this?** I just want to make sure that when i execute some command, the connection to the right ip and port is made.

Comment: If your code is already working, you might want to consider posting this to Code Review, our sister site.

Comment: if you want to make sure the ip and port are correct , you will need to check it every time before invoking any functions that uses this, you can work with a more "efficient" approach, triggers the function and if it gets an error, lookup the ip and port, but you'll need to distinguish between those cases, can you?

Comment: You could create a service that holds the docker client as a private field, along with two other fields for ip and port. Each time `dockerClient` is called, first you check Settings to see if they changed, then accordingly you return the existing client or build a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You build `config` and `dockerCmdExecFactory` every time which probably doesn't needed. As a solution, you could made both fields instead of local variables. But be careful: you have to think about multithreading, how many instances could be and make sure you always initialize fields before calling `dockerClient()`. Probably it's not an problems in your case but you have to check it.

If you use Spring or something like this you could want to create bean which encapsulates all this stuff.

Also probably some framework you have in your app has already implemented connection logic. It would be more preferable since inside framework a lot of optimisation stuff you couldn't realize. Connection/socket pool and exception handling as an example. Try to google 'docker client *your-framework-name*'

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment, you can create a service that holds the docker client state and check if it changes in order to reload or not:

```
class DockerClientService {
    private DockerClient dockerClient;
    private String ip;
    private int port;

    DockerClient getClient() {
        Settings settings = Settings.getSettings();
        if (settings.getDockerPort() != port || !settings.getDockerIP().equals(ip)) {
            port = settings.getDockerPort();
            ip = settings.getDockerIP();
            DockerClientConfig config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
                .withDockerHost("tcp://" + ip + ":" + port)
                .withDockerConfig("/home/user/.docker/config.json")
                .build();

            DockerCmdExecFactory dockerCmdExecFactory = new JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory()
                .withMaxTotalConnections(200)
                .withMaxPerRouteConnections(200);

            dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config)
                .withDockerCmdExecFactory(dockerCmdExecFactory)
                .build();
        }
        return dockerClient;
    }
}
```